# Describing the Inertia group of a number field

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

Let $ K \subseteq L$ be number fields and $\pi$ be a prime ideal of $L$. $G = \operatorname{Gal}\left(L/K\right)$

Let $D = \{\sigma \in G\:|\:\sigma(\pi) = \pi\} $ be the decomposition group for $\pi$ and $I = \{\sigma \in G\:|\:\sigma(\alpha)\equiv\alpha\pmod{\pi}\: \forall \alpha\in\mathcal{O}_{L}\}\subseteq D$ be the inertia group for $\pi$.

We can calculate the number of elements in $D = ef$ easily where e is the ramification index. However, the only proof I have seen of the size of $I$ is by showing that it is the kernel of $D$ in some homomorphism.

Is there a way to describe the $e$ elements of $I$ (or $D$) directly or barring that, some way to show its size directly (only for $I$)?

Edit:I am assuming that $L/K$ is Galois. Thinking a bit more:

Can one define $I$ by the maximal power of $\pi$ that an automorphism $\sigma$ in it fixes as a set? Clearly, every automorphism in $I$ has to fix upto $\pi^{k}$, $1 \leq k \leq e$. Can one show that there is exactly one such automorphism for each $k$? That would directly show the order, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume from your notation and the nature of your question that your extension is Galois. Not particularly easy. First of all, the original proof of the size of $D$ comes from the orbit-stabilizer theorem and the fact that $G$ acts transitively on the primes above the primes of a base field. Ordinarily the constants $e,f$ are easier to compute than $r=|D|$ because of your ability to reduce to a localization or completion and compute there. Computing the order of the inertial subgroup is going to similarly be complicated. You usually use the completion to give yourself a residue field, and then use the surjectivity onto its Galois group to give you the inertial subgroup--which is ultimately a local object anyways when you think about how it's defined.

I would argue that the definition of $I$ is quite direct, and makes sense in terms of the localization, but if that's not to your sensibilities, there's always the so-called "higher ramification theory" approach wherein you pick some $\mathfrak{P}|\mathfrak{p}$ in $L$ and pass to $\mathfrak{P}$-adic completions and then define

$$I=\{\sigma\in G : \min_{x\in\mathcal{O}_{L,\mathfrak{P}}} v_{\mathfrak{P}}(\sigma(x)-x)\ge 0\}.$$

But this is ultimately just a restatement of the definition (albeit a useful one).

---

**Addendum**

Because the comments are getting unwieldy, I'll just add this as a lemma rather than try and continue there.

**Lemma** Let $\sigma$ be a field automorphism and $I,J$ be ideals of a subring of the field. Then $\sigma(IJ)=\sigma(I)\sigma(J)$.

*Proof*:  By definition

> $$IJ=\left\{\sum_{i,j}x_iy_j : x_i\in I, y_j\in J\right\}$$

Then

$$\sigma(IJ)=\left\{\sigma\left(\sum_{i,j}x_iy_j\right): x_i\in I, y_j\in J\right\}$$
$$=\left\{\sum_{i,j}\sigma(x_i)\sigma(y_j): x_i\in I, y_j\in J\right\}$$

because $\sigma$ is a field automorphism

$$=\left\{\sum_{i,j}\sigma(x_i)\sigma(y_j) : \sigma(x_i)\in \sigma(I), \sigma(y_j)\in \sigma(J)\right\}=\sigma(I)\sigma(J)$$

Both of the last two qualities by definition. Setting $I=J=\pi$ and choosing $\sigma\in D$ we get the specific result.

Comment: Can one define $I$ by the power of $\pi$ that an automorphism $\sigma$ in it fixes? Clearly, every automorphism in $I$ has to fix upto $\pi^{k}$, $1 \leq k \leq e$. Can one show that there is exactly one such automorphism for each k? That would directly show the order, correct?

Comment: @Asvin Well, you can define $I$ by looking at the power of the uniformizer, yes:  if you look at that indented alternate definition and then pass to completions, you can see that going over $\mathcal{O}_L$ is silly, you can just test it on a uniformizer, by looking at things in the completion as power series in the uniformizer. At the same time, there clearly is not one such automorphism per $k$, that would be very strange indeed, since $I$ forms a group.

Comment: I am afraid I don't know what an uniformizer or what "higher ramification theory" is :(. I guess I will have to wait a bit to understand this! I don't understand what being a group has to do with fixing $\pi^k$, can you explain a bit?

Comment: @Asvin what do you mean by $\pi$ in your earlier statement? That notation is usually used for a prime element in a DVR also known as a local, uniformizing parameter.

Comment: @Asvin as for the group bit, it makes no sense to talk about individual elements fixing $\pi^k$, if $g\pi^k=\pi^k$ then also $g^2\pi^k =g(g\pi^k))=\pi^k$, so all of $\langle g\rangle$ fixes $\pi^k$, so certainly there are almost never just **one** automorphism that fixes $\pi^k$, any element of order not equal to $2$ will have multiple things fixing it.

Comment: By $\pi$, I meant a prime ideal in $L$ and by fixing $\pi^k$, I meant fixing it as a set. Each automorphism in $I$ fixes $\pi$ but might also fix ideals as a set upro $\pi^e$ and I wanted to enumerate $I$ by the minimal such ideal it fixes and maybe describe the group operation wrt to this minimal ideal too. I could have been much clearer, sorry!

Comment: @Asvin I see. Well, you don't really care so much about fixing the ideal, as you do fixing things modulo the ideal. Note that since $I\subseteq D$ things in $I$ always fix the ideal as a set, so it's rather uninteresting. And since the ideals form a group, all of $D$ also fixes $\pi^k$ for all $k$, so as $I\subseteq D$ again, you won't get any useful information about things that way. The reason you complete is that Henselian rings are very nice and can be used to describe your group $I$ in terms of other useful invariants. If you have yet to encounter this machinery, I recommend [continued]

Comment: @Asvin [continued] reading on it in the appropriate chapters of something like Serre's *Local Fields* or Neukirch's *Algebraic Number Theory*, both of which I find are excellent references on the subject. If not, then there's also no harm in waiting, the answer to your immediate question is that we don't currently have any general methods for computing orders as you are seeking, at least none available with the machinery you're currently working with.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendations! If you don't mind one last question, why should $D$ fix $\pi^k$ as a group? An automorphism fixing a set might not fix a subset, correct? Is there anything particular to $D$ that fixes all the ideals?

Comment: @Asvin by definition $D$ is associated to a specific prime (decomposition groups are conjugate) and defined as the stabilizer of $\pi$ as a set. In other words it's **defined** as the things in $G$ which fix $\pi$ as a set.

Comment: Yes, but it may fix $\pi$ and not fix $\pi^2$, correct?

Comment: @Asvin check my edit to my answer, I figured it was easier that continuing to comment. Hopefully that helps explain things.

Comment: Thanks, that settles things!

Comment: @Asvin I'm glad we could find an answer you'd find acceptable and accessible. Best of luck in your studies.